# AWS roles: Give very granular permission for deleting something from elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, redis, amazon-iam, amazon-elasticache

I want to write a lambda function that only deletes a very specific set of keys from an ElastiCache cluster (Redis). I'm trying to define the proper permission in its role to allow it to do that. What are the minimum permissions I can give the function in order to be able to just delete the keys?

Comment: Even if you are using IAM authentication for your Redis cluster, the IAM policy only controls the permission to connect to the cluster. It does not apply to specific Redis commands or specific keys in the Redis database. For that you would need to use the Redis ACL https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/

Comment: I see. So, basically only the "connect" permission under the "write" access level is needed to perform this as far as AWS is concerned? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ElastiCache introduced [IAM Authentication](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-elasticache-supports-iam-authentication-redis-clusters/) starting Redis 7. This means you can now create Redis users (Using the [CreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUser.html) action) and set the authentication mode to IAM. This will result in the user having to authenticate using a short-lived IAM authentication token.

When creating a Redis user, you can also provide an access string which provides a form of authorization. The access string supports [Redis' ACL](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/) and provides a way to restrict access to commands and keys. Note there's no category specifically for "delete". You'll need to grant "write" permissions in order for the user to actually delete a key.

The following AWS CLI command will create a Redis user that needs to authenticate using IAM and can only access specific keys that adhere to a specific pattern:

```
aws elasticache create-user \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --user-id bob \
  --user-name bob \ 
  --engine Redis \
  --authentication-mode Type=iam \
  --access-string "on ~todelete* -@all +@write"
```